# How to load dynamically all modules from a folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Structure of Program is like this:

```
   ├── loader.py
    └── plugins
        ├── first.py
        └── __init__.py
```

`loader.py` contains code to load modules and it's like this:

```
import importlib.util
import os

search_dir = "./plugins"
plugins_module = []

def loader():
    path = os.path.realpath(search_dir)
    for module in os.listdir(path):
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module.split(".")[0], os.path.join(path,module))
        plugin_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(plugin_module)
        plugins_module.append(plugin_module)

loader()
```

content of `__init__.py` is :

```
from first import hello
def main():
    print("hello from __init__.py")
    hello()
```

And `first.py` looks like this:

```
def hello():
    print("hello from first.py")
```

But loader gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loader.py", line 15, in <module>
    loader()
  File "loader.py", line 12, in loader
    spec.loader.exec_module(plugin_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/vishal/Programs/stack/plugins/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from first import hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'first'
```

Comment: Try `from .first import hello`

Comment: It doesn't work and i can't change the files under plugins directory. I want to change it in Loader.py

Comment: What about `from plugins.first import hello` (I: putting in the full relative path)?